# wrong alignment with text and numbers

Tags: joomla, alignment

i have problem 
in my site for example when i want to show comment(1) instead of that i see )comment(1 what should i do ?
i using Joomla
but in source code it is correct

```
<div class="kmt-readon">

            <span class="kmt-comment aligned-left">
        <a href="http://www.rouzbeh17th.com/index.php/menu-site/menu-site-ann/1-2013-12-24-19-57-23#section-kmt">Comment (1)</a>
    </span>

        </div>      </div>
```

i think there is problem with CSS code to show that in this shape
help me dudes
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by `text-direction`. Are you using an RTL template?

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.kmt-readon { text-direction:ltr; }
```